# Parse XML with javascript from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, url

Helo, I'm a beginner in javascript,

For a project, I need to parse an XML File with JS, I'm using Jquery.

How can I open xml by its url please?

```
var xml = "Fichier.xml",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
```

I have an error at this line `xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),`
 : Invalid XML : test.xml (error 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) expects a valid xml content as its argument, in your case you have a url which is not a valid xml thus your are getting the error.

What you can do is to use a [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load the remote content and in its success callback you can do your processing

```
var xml = "Fichier.xml";
$.get(xml, function (doc) {
    var $xml = $(doc);
    //do stuff with $xml
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: $title = $xml.find( "title" );
     
It says that $xml doesn't exist I don't understand

Comment: @ItMoreSimplePlease where did you place the code.. did you place it next after `var $xml = $(doc);` or after `}, 'xml');`

Comment: I placed it after, now I placed it before and it's working thank you a lot

Comment: @ItMoreSimplePlease go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call to see why it is